# Apache Document Root adds leading default path

Tags: apache, ubuntu

This should be a very simple question to answer for people who knows apache.

I have an Ubuntu computer which I use as my server. I have worked with apache several times before, but never experienced this issue.

My owncloud.conf file in the sites-enabled folder looks like this:

`1 <VirtualHost *:80>¬
 2     ServerName owncloud¬
 3     DocumentRoot "~/mybook/ownCloud"¬
 4     <Directory ~/mybook/ownCloud/>¬
 5         Options None¬
 6         Order deny,allow¬
 7         Allow from all¬
 8     </Directory>¬
 9 </VirtualHost>`

But after enabling the site and restarting apache, I'm getting this error:

`AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/etc/apache2/~/mybook/ownCloud] does not exist`

I've been looking, and I cannot seem to find where it's set that "/etc/apache2/" should be leading default path to all set document roots of the site config files.

Does anyone know how I can remove this default setting?

Comment: is this a Macbook or Mac OS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget the comment I made regarding Mac, what you have above will not work. If you installed Apache on Ubuntu and accepted the defaults the docroot is /var/www and I am assuming you want your /mybook/ownCloud mapped to docroot. That is how you should do it because the httpd will run with group permissions to the real docroot. That can be done using an alias as I have below. Look at the bottom, but also note that I specified the correct default docroot in the beginning before I mapped anything. You can change the docroot but you will have to make sure the permissions on the new directory structure are set correctly.

I aliased your /mybook/ownCloud/ to ownCloud. Also, I have other directives that I removed from the sites-enabled code below for clarity.

BTW, I have personally never used tildes within an Apache conf file like you have above, it could be confusing during startup.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

  Alias /owncloud/ "/mybook/ownCloud"
    <Directory "/mybook/ownCloud">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

EDIT: 
There are other ways to configure a VHost, but this is basically how it is done. You no longer set a server wide docroot declaration in httpd.conf. The /etc/apache2/ path is the server home and in the absence of a docroot declaration in your sites-enabled it may have defaulted to Server Home when httpd started.

Comment: Thank you very much, but how I did it is they way I've always done it. I feel this is more a quick workaround, as I don't want many links in my apache2 folder.

I can't remember what I did when I installed it, but I most likely set the default path to /etc/apache2/, but surely there must be a way to edit and remove that. That's basically what I want to know. But thank you for your answer!

Comment: You're welcome, but this is the way you want to configure a VHost for Apache. It is not a workaround. It used to be that you would have declared the docroot in httpd.conf along with other server variables. But when 2.2 came out the configuration changed as far as file layout. There are other ways to configure this.

Comment: Ah ok, I used to work with this a couple of years back or so. Must have changed since then. I also found out that it didn't like tilde. Whenever I used ~, it added the leading path, so I had to enter the full path to the folder. Thank you very much though, I will use your way. Cheers

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Read more about what has changed from you prior experience. I too had that speed bump when I went to 2.2. It broke all my WebDav for SVN config. took about 1 week to get it all going again.    http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/